# How to hide specific variables in Pojo classes while generating JSON responses

Tags: java, jersey, pojo

I am trying to hide some fields in a Pojo class while generating Json responses. Assume there are 4 variables in my java class. In the first response, I need all variables to be generated in the json object. For the next response, I only need 3 variables in the json object.

(The hiding part possibly be implemented when object creation and not inside the class implementation.) Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to provide some samples that you tried and didn't work so that we could help you here. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you can use the GSON library to dynamically remove some fields. Please refer https://memorynotfound.com/dynamically-exclude-json-fields-with-gson-from-object/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with [`@JsonView`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) feature. This feature allows you to define multiple "views" = set of attributes, for a given class.

Each view is a simple marker class. for convinience, you can put them all inside one wrapper class (it can even be the pojo class itself)

```
public class PojoViews {
    public static class Response1{}
    public static class Response2{}
    public static class Response3{}
}
```

The view classes are specified as annotation for every attributre that is to be included in seralization

```
public class Pojo {

    @JsonView({PojoViews.Response1.class, PojoViews.Response2.class, PojoViews.Response3.class})
    public String attr1;
    @JsonView({PojoViews.Response1.class, PojoViews.Response2.class, PojoViews.Response3.class})
    public int attr2;
    @JsonView({PojoViews.Response1.class, PojoViews.Response2.class})
    public double attr3;
    @JsonView(PojoViews.Response1.class)
    public boolean attr4;
}
```

at runtime, you can assign a particular view to produce desired set af attributes

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Class<?> view = Pojo.Response2.class;  // runtime assignment of view
mapper.writerWithView(view).writeValue(System.out, pojo);
```